# Nodejs website execution in the background

Tags: node.js, sms, redirect, http-redirect, sms-gateway

So I am developing a call logging website based on Nodejs, I have come to a point from where I need to send SMS to the engineer when the call is logged. I have got access to the SMS gateway which is essentially a URL like the following :
http://192.x.x.x username=x password=y&to=**mobileno**&text=xyz

My requirement is to execute this link so that the SMS is sent and the page remains as it was without having to be redirected.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

What i understood from your description is you have to hit the url after certain task.So u can use a rest client to hit the url in the callback of certain task(here after call is logged).
I prefer node-rest-client(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client).There are other options also.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple task due to node.js io asynchrony.

Suppose you have an express route:

```
app.get('/some-url', (req, res) => {
   request('http://192.x.x.x?username=x&password=y&to=mobileno&text=xyz')
     .then(response => { // process response }) 

   res.end();

});
```